# calling modules in a python file more than once

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm trying to make a really basic operating system using just python and it goes like this:

```
print ("welcome to ben's operating system V 0.1.0")
ten = 0
while (ten < 1000000):
    do = input()
    if do == ("pythag"):
        from bensos import pythag
    elif do == ("word"):
        from bensos import word
    else :
        print ("invalid input")
```

the pythag code is this

```
from math import sqrt
a = float(input ("a="))

b = float(input ("b="))
a = a*a

b = b*b

c = a+b

c = sqrt (c)
print ("c=")
print (c)
d = input("end")
```

I've only got two programs on it and the word one doesnt work, and I havent got the loop thing perfect but it works. The problem I'm having is the reload code; I put it on the bottom and it says some kind of error, so I tried putting it into the module and still came up with an error. Without the reload it runs fine but I can only use the modules once and I've looked everywhere and nothing helped.

Comment: can you post the whole errors?

Comment: "some knid of error" is really not helpful. What is the actual error? What is the "reload code" you're talking about, for that matter, since you're not showing us that either?

Comment: reload(pythag) i saw something like that and i came up with an error il try to see what it said

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off putting all of the imports at the top, so

```
from bensos import pythag
from bensos import word
...
```

and then in the pythag and word module define a procedure runModule and fill that with all of the code that is currently in the module.

```
def runModule():
    #The contents of your files at the moment
```

So your pythag file would look like

```
from math import sqrt

def runModule():
    a = float(input ("a="))

    b = float(input ("b="))
    a = a*a

    b = b*b

    c = a+b

    c = sqrt (c)
    print ("c=")
    print (c)
    d = input("end")
```

That way, your code will load the modules first and then you can call them whenever you want like

```
pythag.runModule()
```

Let me know if that wasn't clear, or if you still have troubles.

Comment: right im pretty sure what you mean but i still think i did it wrong                                                               
 if do == ("pythag"):
  pythag.runpythag

Comment: i did everything you said and in the if function to run the pythag do i just put pythag.runpythag beacuse thats what you said to call it but when i run the cose nothing happens

Comment: you would call pythag.runModule()

Comment: oh oops thats a silly mistake even for me thanks it works now :D

Comment: thx ill be adding more to my os probably be hearing from me again